# Regex to match any letter, space or specific number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I'm trying to create a regex to match all letters or spaces or specific number.

Here's what I have.

```
([a-zA-Z\s24]*)
```

```
 #but this is matching a 2 or a 4, i need exactly 24 only

ex:
- asdfafasf asfasdf  #should match asdfafasf asfasdf
- asdf asdf asdf 24  #should match asdf asdf asdf 24
- asdf24asdfasdf as  #should match asdf24asdfasdf as
- asdfadf2 asdf      #should match asdfadf
- asdfasdf kljl 6    #should match asdfasdf kljl
```

https://regex101.com/r/iNWuRb/1

Comment: It should be: `([a-zA-Z\s]+|24)`

Comment: Try `^(?:24|[a-zA-Z\s])+`

Comment: try it with this site. It could help [regex tester](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a sequence of chars into a character class. A character class is meant to match a single char defined in the character class, thus, what you did can't work.

You need to use a *grouping construct*, an alternation group, and acc. to the expected matches, you need to only match at the start of the string:

```
^(?:24|[a-zA-Z\s])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Z5Rpu/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:24|[a-zA-Z\s])+` - one or more occurrences of:

  - `24` - a substring `24`
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-zA-Z\s]` - an ASCII letter or whitespace

Comment: yes, I think this is close except now I need to group the second result. Group 1 should be all letters (or 24) until it hits a number. Group 2 should be the number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]*|24)
```

Then you get your group of A-Z\s or the number 24.